# Twitter login doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, twitter, authentication, localhost

I'll to make a login screen whit asp.NET where you can use third providers to login like Facebook and Twitter. Facebook works good but if I do it whit Twitter I've got a problem.

> The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The site I will add to the setting must be localhost, but Twitter doesn't accept this.

Comment: That error is caused by an invalid certificate, not by invalid credentials. What URL is is connecting to?

Comment: @stuartd: For this moment is it only localhost. But if I enter that into the settings, Says twitter that it is an invalid format